# Determine sequential numbers in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, sequential

I'm trying to find the most pythonic way to find out if numbers in a list are sequential. To give some background, I have a list of numbers gathered that exist in a folder, and I need to find out which numbers are missing.

I gather all of the numbers, and then make another list from the range(beginning, end+1) of what numbers should be there. I very easily made something to show me all of the numbers missing:

```
missing = [x for x in existingNumbers if x not in shouldBeNumbers]
```

The problem is that if I print out all of those, there are a lot of numbers that could be condensed (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10 could be printed as 1-4, 7, 10) because there could be massive amounts of numbers missing.

I've tried two approaches:

For both ways, frameRange is range(startFrame, endFrame+1) and frameList is a list generated from what exists currently.

1)

```
    for x in frameRange:
        if x not in frameList:
            if originalFrame == None:
                originalFrame = x
            elif originalFrame:
                if lastFrame == None:
                    lastFrame = x
                elif lastFrame:
                    if lastFrame == x-1:
                        lastFrame = x
                    else:
                        if originalFrame != lastFrame:
                            missingFrames.append(str(originalFrame)+"-"+str(lastFrame))
                            originalFrame = x
                            lastFrame = x
                        else:
                            missingFrames.append(str(originalFrame))
                            originalFrame = x
                            lastFrame = x
        if x == endFrame:
            if originalFrame != lastFrame:
                missingFrames.append(str(originalFrame)+"-"+str(lastFrame))
                originalFrame = x
                lastFrame = x
            else:
                missingFrames.append(str(originalFrame))
                originalFrame = x
                lastFrame = x
```

2)

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(frameRange):
        if frameRange[i] in frameList:
            i += 1
        else:
            if i + 1 < len(frameRange):
                if frameRange[i + 1] in frameList:
                    missingFrames.append(str(frameRange[i]))
                    i += 1
                else:
                    j = 1
                    while frameRange[i+j] not in frameList:
                        aheadFrameNumber = int(str(j))
                        if i + j + 1 < len(frameRange):
                            j += 1
                        else:
                            break
                    missingFrames.append(str(frameRange[i])+"-"+str(frameRange[aheadFrameNumber]))
                    if i + aheadFrameNumber + 1 < len(frameRange):
                        i += aheadFrameNumber + 1
            else:
                missingFrames.append(str(frameRange[i]))
```

The first way was working, but since it happens on the current frame checking the last, whenever the last frame was gone it wouldn't append the last missing section to the list. For the second way I had to keep wrapping everything in if statements because I kept getting index exceptions when moving forwards.

I think I have to step back, re-think, and approach it differently. I'm wondering if there is a much better way to do this in python that I haven't thought about yet because I don't know the function. Both ways started to get a little out of hand.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a typical list that you want to look through? eg. could it be something like `[1,3,4,5,6,3,10,12]`? or `[1,2,3,4,7,17,18,19,20]`.  Also, what would be the desired outcome based on the given examples?

Comment: A typical list is a folder with numbered files. The files could be well into the thousands, the largest list so far is 13k (usually only 2k). The files get added sequentially in batches of around 20. So it's possible for this kind of existing list: `[1,2,3,21,22,23,24]` where the expected total would be 1-100. That would ouput `"MISSING: 4-20, 25-100"`

Also, I've updated my original post with my solution after I left it alone for a while. It works, but if you have any suggestions, do tell. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
missing=[]
numbers.insert(0, 0) # add the minimum value on begining of the list
numbers.append(41)  # add the maximum value at the end of the list
for rank in xrange(0, len(numbers)-1):
   if numbers[rank+1] - numbers[rank] > 2:
      missing.append("%s-%s"%(numbers[rank] +1 , numbers[rank+1] - 1))
   elif numbers[rank+1] - numbers[rank] == 2:
      missing.append(str(numbers[rank]+1))

print missing
```

which for `numbers = [1,4,6,10, 12,]` and numbers should be present are from 1 to 40 you will have :

```
['2-3', '5', '7-9', '11', '13-40']
```

Comment: I see that works for scenarios when the beginning and end numbers of the existing list are the beginning and end numbers of the should-be-there list. However, along with the existing list, a should-be beginning and end number are supplied. So if there should be numbers 1 through 1000 are there, and only 30 through 100 are actually there, this will only show numbers between 30 and 100 that are missing.

Comment: You should update your question to clarify this. I was working on something similar to this answer but would not have guessed your needs from your Original Q...

Comment: I am sorry, I see how it could be misunderstood. Thank you for trying to help. It is updated.

Comment: Why `11-40` when you have 12 in your data?

Comment: Okay, so now that you have pasted from your shell, why is 11 missing from your results?

Comment: I have incorporated this answer, and it works the same as my solution in my updated question. By the way, you were missing a ")" on line 6. Also, for the insert and append, I have changed it to a variable -/+ 1, so when I specify `beg=1` and `end=100`, it is `numbers.insert(0, beg-1)` and `numbers.append(end+1)`

Comment: @hughdbrown : now, everything is the same than in my shell... sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_missing_range(my_numbers, range_min, range_max):
    expected_range = set(range(range_min, range_max + 1))
    return expected_range - set(my_numbers)

def numbers_as_ranges(numbers):
    ranges = []
    for number in numbers:
        if ranges and number == (ranges[-1][-1] + 1):
            ranges[-1] = (ranges[-1][0], number)
        else:
            ranges.append((number, number))
    return ranges

def format_ranges(ranges):
    range_iter = (("%d" % r[0] if r[0] == r[1] else "%d-%d" % r) for r in ranges)
    return "(" + ", ".join(range_iter) + ")"

def main(my_numbers, range_min, range_max):
    numbers_missing = find_missing_range(my_numbers, range_min, range_max)
    ranges = numbers_as_ranges(numbers_missing)
    return format_ranges(ranges)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    range_min, range_max = 1, 40
    print main([1, 4, 6, 10, 12], range_min, range_max)
    print main([1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20], range_min, range_max)

(2-3, 5, 7-9, 11, 13-40)
(5-9, 11-19, 21-40)
```